# How can i highlight the items in a horizontal listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, highlight

Hi all how can i highlight the items in a horizontal listview in android. I have implemented the highlight but it does not persist in horizontal listview. I think it is the problem of horizontal listview because the highlight is works fine in simple listview. Can anyone please help me to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my horizontal listview:

```
<com.extraslice.gmobile.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/listViewadmin_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dip" />
```

The list_item_background.xml is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/org_blue" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_orgs" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_orgs" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

I have included the list_item_background.xml in listview item like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
   android:id="@+id/agent_layout"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
  android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Please give me a solution to highlight the horizontal listview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying this to template,try using applying selector to listview

```
<com.extraslice.gmobile.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewadmin_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip" />
```

hope it may help.

Comment: Try putting this code in list_item_backgound     '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false">
 <color android:color="#3A3A3A"/>
        </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#3A3A3A"/>
 </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false">
      <color android:color="#3A3A3A"/>
</item>
</selector>'

Comment: I tried, but its not working. The selection is not persisting. While i am selecting, the item is highlighting. But the hight is not persisting.

Comment: Well i guess you need to maintain the state of the view from your java file, like  view.setSelected(boolean);

Comment: private OnItemClickListener onItem = new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
   
   arg1.setSelected(true);
   mHlvCustomList.setSelection(arg2);
   
  
        arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_orgs);
   
      
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked item"+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   
  
  }
 };